# Integer values in difference equations

Tags: econometrics

In difference equations, the time variable $t$ can only take integer values. Does this imply that the variable $y_t$ must be considered a discrete variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A continous variable ($y_t$) can be indexed by a discrete variable ($t $).